# How does the product of sum form work?

Tags: boolean-algebra

How does the product of sum form work? I understand that you take the product of the sums of the negated inputs of all rows of the truth table whose output is false. Taking XOR for example:

| A | B | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

The product of sum form would be:

$(\bar A + \bar B)(A + B)$

However, I don't understand why this method yields the correct boolean equation?

I understand why the sum of product form works but the product of sum form seems quite unintuitive to me.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your example, we have the logical expression:

Using similar logic to the sum of product form, we know that:

${(\bar A \bar B) + (AB)} = F$

Therefore:

$\overline{(\bar A \bar B) + (AB)} = T$

With continuous application of Demorgan's Theorem ($\overline{X+Y} = \bar X \bar Y$):

$\overline{(\bar A \bar B)}  \overline{(AB)} = T$

$(\bar{\bar A } + \bar{\bar B})  (\bar A + \bar B) = T$

$(A + B)  (\bar A + \bar B) = T$

As desired.